# Which is the correct preposition to use?

Tags: prepositions

I belong to a group of teachers who are currently working on our school yearbook.  I am in the editing stage and I came across this title.  Prepositions are a tricky part of speech.  Which is the correct preposition to use in this phrase ...My favorite memory 'of' or 'in' Grade ... thank you.

Comment: You must give more context, i.e. full sentence that is more meaningful and you should say who (teachers or students) will write this. ++ In broad terms: **Of** = associated with; related to ++ **In** = during the course of  (**In** can be used to introduce a memory that is not directly associated with Grade X - Compare "My favourite memory in 2012 was my sister's marriage. My present favourite memory is of my holiday in Bali")

Comment: I'd say the difference is, was it your favorite memory while your were in grade x or is it your favorite memory of grade x.

Comment: It depends if you're talking about your favourite memory from among all of those you had **during** the school year (*in*) or **about** the school year (*of*).